# How to get information form link clicks?

Tags: hyperlink, analytics, data-analysis

I am wondering how it is possible to get information from link clicks.

For example, a user is logged in and clicks a link. Is it possible to record that information? Number of links clicked, which ones, etc... things like that.

I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas / links to information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to bind an event to your links and have the logging done that way.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662434/click-logging-with-javascript).

You also might try looking at setting up **[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)** on your site; it's a free service that offers incredible amounts of data collecting for your site. Here's a blog post that details [tracking clicks with Google Analytics](http://www.epikone.com/blog/2007/03/13/tracking-clicks-with-google-analytics-pt-0/).

Comment: Thanks. I know about Google Analytics, but I want to generate the information myself.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- read the statistics from logs on the web server
- use redirects through different URL
- use your own JavaScript code executed in `onclick` attribute

*Update*: there is `ping` attribute for `a` element. Web browser will then send a notification to the specified link. In HTML5 though.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is by passing the user through a redirect link of your own. So the links go to http://yourserver.com/redir.aspx?realink=<url encoded link>